# Has George Lucas ever explained why Obi-Wan doesn't remember R2?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi, r2-d2

Probably at the time he didn't even have the backstory in his head, but did Lucas ever explain why Obi-Wan Kenobi didn't recognize R2-D2 in "A New Hope"?

Comment: By Lucas do you literally mean George Lucas or do you mean Lucasfilm?

Comment: Would you recognise your old phone from 20 years ago?  Or just think "huh, I used to have one that looked like that..."  The prequels show Astromechs as being common and mass produced - I doubt there's only one in the galaxy that's blue.